# Debugging Blazor WebAssembly in VSCode (linux) doesn't work

Tags: c#, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I try to debug a Blazor WebAssembly app in Ubuntu, using VSCode. I'm able to start the application from VSCode **but it doesn't hit at any breakpoints**.

**What I did**
I followed the guides from Microsoft:

- [Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code)
- [Tooling for ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=linux)

just created a new standard project using

```sh
dotnet new blazorwasm -o BlazorWasmApplication1
```

I'm using the original code from the template.

**Properties/launchSettings.json**

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:11236",
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BlazorWasmLinux": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7242;http://localhost:5285",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorWasmLinux.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorWasmLinux.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "--project",
                "${workspaceFolder}/BlazorWasmLinux.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "url": "https://localhost:7242",
            "browser": "chrome"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what the debug console shows me.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Using launch settings from '/home/BooFar/MyProjects/learningblazor/BlazorWasmLinux/Properties/launchSettings.json' [Profile 'BlazorWasmLinux']...
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
... 
... Many entries like the above, loading dlls 
...
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7242
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5285
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/BooFar/MyProjects/learningblazor/BlazorWasmLinux
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Net.Requests.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Net.Sockets.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Formats.Asn1.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/System.ComponentModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

The application pops up in a separate window. Hovering over the breakpoint shows **`unbound breakpoint`**. And of course it doesn't stop there when executing the code.
[image: Breakpoint]

Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is there any known bug? Or any alternative approaches?
Thanks in advance.

**MyEnvironment**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- google-chrome (Version 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)),
- .Net 6.0.101
- VSCode 1.63.2 with the current version of the extensions [C# for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.VSCode.BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.blazorwasm-companion).

Comment: I also had this problem. I found a workaround, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037574) for working config.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it was a bug in .NET SDK/runtime? Not really sure
See also [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/39995).

After updating to .NET Net 6.0.102 the code stopped at the position I was able to step through the code.

Additinally I had to start http not https, but this is a different story (certificate).

**So the solution was updating .NET sdk.**